# QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Tags: c++, qt5

I want to create a PDF with Qt. This is my code:

```cpp
#include <QPdfWriter>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main() {
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter{R"(C:\TEMP\test.pdf)"};
    QTextDocument document;
    document.setPlainText("Hello world");
    document.print(&pdfWriter);
}
```

It crashes on the last line with

> QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a `QApplication`. Change the code to

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPdfWriter>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QPdfWriter pdfWriter{R"(C:\TEMP\test.pdf)"};
    QTextDocument document;
    document.setPlainText("Hello world");
    document.print(&pdfWriter);
}
```

and it will create the PDF. Running `app.exec()` is not required.